# JAVA AWT SWING code to be ported to Android NDK

Tags: java, android, swing

I have application already written in JAVA Applet/Swing and want it to port to Android.
My questions are:
1) How much is the change of socket,threads, APIs changed in Android? Are the frameworks different?
2) Any way to reuse AWT/Swing code in Android? If not whats the best alternative and easy way out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sockets and threading are vanilla java - so no change there, end everything is expected to work.  UI stuff and application lifecycle were changed radically, so your you will have to develop everythign UI related anew.

Good news is, that UI stuff is more sane and easier to work with than with applets.

Comment: Thanks for prompt answer can u tell me any document which can give me direction on how to convert existing ui layer from AWT/SWING to android layer.

Comment: I'm affraid that there is no such document -  APIs and programming model differ.  Start by reading android tutorials.  You will be able  to reuse some of networking  and threading stuff - but nothing from inteface.  Android UI is 10 yrats ahead of AWT (which  was deprecated 10 years ago)